# Wordpress Permalink problem on current site (Wp Network)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, permalinks, wordpress

I'm using wordpress. **Installed in the subfolder.** (webroot/blog)

Permalinks was **before**: http ://www.mysite.com **/blog/** sample-post.html

I actived the network.

Permalinks **after**: http ://www.mysite.com **/blog/blog/** sample-post.html

**wp-config.php**

```
...
    define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
    define( 'MULTISITE', true );
    define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
    $base = '/blog/';
    define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.mysite.com' );
    define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/' );
    define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
    define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
...
```

**Main Site Permalink Settings**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyhWf.jpg

---

### how to do it?

http://www.mysite.com/blog/sample-post.html

Comment: try setting your `$base` to '/'

Comment: @Cronco I did but the result is the same.

**$base = '/';** and **define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );**
Result:Error establishing database connection

Answer (score 0):

If you activated network you cannot have the wordpress installed in a sub directory. It has to be in your html directory.

You might want to use a subdomain, or if you are not using network, disable it.

Comment: But, I do not use sub-domains. I use the folder. Such as these:
example: http://www.mysite.com/blog/SITE-1-BASE-URL/sample-post.html
http://www.mysite.com/blog/SITE-2-BASE-URL/tags/foo
This works.

Comment: This is what I am trying to point out. If you go through wp network documentation, it clearly slates it does not function properly within a folder..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install a network in a folder. Where people get confused in the warnings is there part where they misread the information given.

you cannot install a network in a folder and run the address off the root.

This has no relevence to your problem, but I'm clarifying it for other answerers.

the /blog/ in your permalinks is added to the main blog only to prevent collisions. Look for the "remove blog permalink" plugin.

in 3.0 there was a bug allowing you to remove this manually.